# how i can run my c++ simple helloworld code automatically when linux boot

Tags: linux, boot

I searched a lot about this. for now i put script in directory
/etc/init.d
script:

```
   dir="/home/sajid/Desktop"
   cmd="./hello"
   user="root"
```

my Hello word code is in desktop. its executable file is also in desktop. to run the code I have to type ./hello in terminal that's why I putted ./hello in "cmd" variable in script .
now I don't know how to check it

Answer (score 0):

That is not a proper script. The scripts in `/etc/init.d` are normal shell scripts. Not a set of variables.

The script in your case could be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/sajid/Desktop
./hello > output.txt
```

make the script executable.

The `cd` command will switch into the directory where your script is.

The redirection `> output.txt` will print result of your application into text file. Without it - the application will print to `stdout` which exists during boot time and later replaced by your GUI.

And the script is already run by `root` as all scripts in `/etc/init.d` are.

Comment: i have tried this also . its not creating output.txt file . when i reboot my system

Comment: @Sajid Check what you did. There is a typo in your scripts.

Comment: @Sajid Pleased edit your post to show the content of the script you created. Also, try the command `/etc/init.d/myscript` and show the output.